# How to stop unwanted reoccurence using @foreach in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How would it be possible to prevent the duplication of text that is not needed. Look at picture below (Areas with the red lines). It seems to be a loop issue but with not being familiar with the razor syntax am struggling a little. I am new to MVC4 just trying a little project out and still learning so any help would be appreciated.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Destinations()
{
   string[] departureAirports = new string[3] { "Edinburgh", "London", "Manchester" };
   string[] dCode = new string[3] { "EDI", "LTN", "MAN" };

   var destinationList = new List<Destination>();

   foreach (var airport in departureAirports)
   {
        destinationList.Add(new Destination() { departureName = airport });
   }
   foreach (var code in dCode)
   {
        destinationList.Add(new Destination() { departureCode = code });
   }            
        return View(destinationList);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Flight.Models.Destination>

<table>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        <tr>
            <td>Departure Name:</td>
            <td>@item.departureName</td>
            <td>Departure Code:</td>
            <td>@item.departureCode</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Model:

```
public class Destination
{
    public string departureName { get; set; }

    public string departureCode { get; set; }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: you'r probably better of editing your Destination class so it contains both departureName and departureCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the airport code with the city by placing it on one list. You are staggering the airports. I think you are intending to combine them.

```
string[] departureAirports = new string[3] { "Edinburgh,EDI", "London,LTN", "Manchester,MAN" };
foreach (string airport in departureAirports)
{
    string[] data=airport.Split(',');    
    destinationList.Add(new Destination() { departureName = data[0], departureCode=data[1]});
}

return View(destinationList);
```

Comment: how many pieces of data can you match together using this method do you know and is it just the same technique as as above? thanks very useful

Comment: Use as many elements as you need, however, an airport could conceivably have a "," in the name, for example, a typo. You may be better served using a @ or | to split the data.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not in Razor code but how you create your `destinationList` model. You add `departureAirports` and then add `dCode` at the end. You can use LINQ [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to merge 2 arrays together:

```
var destinationList = departureAirports
                         .Zip(dCode, (airport, code) => new Destination() { departureName = airport, departureCode = code })
                         .ToList();
```

or simply create `destinationList` as `List<Destination>` without any convertion:

```
var destinationList = new List<Destination>
    {
        new Destination{ departureCode = "EDI", departureName = "Edinburgh" },
        new Destination{ departureCode = "LTN", departureName = "London" },
        new Destination{ departureCode = "MAN", departureName = "Manchester" }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Razor syntax. The problem is inside your Controller. Let me explain what is happening here.

You have created a View, which is bound to a Model - `List<Destination>`. This means that when you return a `View` with an object of the type `List<Detsination` passed as an argument to the contructor, this object will get bound to the `View` object that will be rendered. Now, this view will automatically display the content in your model object properly, if your Razor syntax is right, which it is. The problem, then, is within your model object.

This model object (`destinationList`) is created in the controller, which is then passed as an argument to `View`. Look at how this `destinationList` is filled. You have two separate loops to fill in values of two separate properties of the `Destination` object and then add it to the list. However, even when you assign a value to only one property, the entire `Destination` object is created, but the value of the other property is set to the default value of its type - in this case `null`.

In your second loop, when you assign values to the `departureCode` property, the values are assigned to the property of a new `Departure` object everytime. You probably want `"EDI"` assigned to the `departureCode` of the same `Destination` object that has the value of the `departureName` property set to `"Edinburgh"`. But this doesn't happen because a new `Departure` object is being created when you assign `"EDI"` to 'deprtureCode`.

So instead of having the following `Departure` objects:

```
Departure [ departureName = "Edinburgh" , departureCode = "EDI" ]
Departure [ departureName = "London" , departureCode = "LTN"]
Departure [ departureName = "Manchester", departureCode = "MAN"]
```

You end up having:

```
Departure [ departureName = "Edinburgh", departureCode = null]
Departure [ departureName = "London", departureCode = null]
Departure [ departureName = "Manchester", departureCode = null]
Departure [ departureName = null, departureCode = "EDI"]
Departure [ departureName = null, departureCode = "LTN"]
Departure [ departureName = null, departureCode = "MAN"]
```

And hence the result of the view.

You should change your code to:

```
int destinationCount = departureAirports.Count;

for(int i = 0; i < destinationCount ; i++)
    destinationList.Add(new Destination() { departureName = departureAirports[i], departureCode = dCode[i];
```

But do this only if you are sure that the departure code at each position in your `dCode` array matches the airport name at the corresponding position in your `destinationAirports` array.

Otherwise follow @Irb's suggestion.